# Class not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I create class in namespace Anketa_3.App_Code and want using it in my controller. I add lib:
[using Anketa_3.App_Code]

I change namespaces and location file, but it wasn't work

Here my class:
(https://ibb.co/FWsKfBX)
Here i want using class
(https://ibb.co/GcS4FF4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work, because you have parameterized constructor. You can use as

```
LoadAccessTestsFromExcel testsFromExcel = new LoadAccessTestsFromExcel(new Stream());
```

Comment: I initialize constructor in method: 

`[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase upload) 
{ 
   if (upload != null) 
   { 
      ex = new LoadAccessTestsFromExcel(upload.InputStream); 
      if (ex.haveErrors) 
         return CheckErrors(); 
   } 
   return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
}`

Comment: @JohannesKrauserIII LoadAccessTestsFromExcel testsFromExcel should work but will be null if not initialized. The problem is he is not getting the reference to the class.

Comment: @Rahatur but othes class working and defined [img](https://ibb.co/r7WV80w)

Comment: I created the same file in a test application and I am also not getting the reference, so I moved the class from App_Code to App_Data and Services and from both the folders I can get the reference.

Comment: @JohannesKrauserIII That is the problem he is having and looking for answer here - LoadAccessTestsFromExcel is not being recognized.

Comment: Check the property of the class, if it is content then change it to compile

Comment: I create file in other folder and relocate it to App_Code folder. And all working now. Thanks @Jitan Gupta